What was a 1980s kids tv show where the characters soved crimes with math
I have memories of watching a kids tv show where crimes (or something like that the memory is vague) with math of something like that. It featured during normal kids viewing times in Australia at the time.

It was played in australia not sure where it was made
Colour
Two main characters one male one female. 
Not a cartoon, no puppets

Im not entirely sure when it was created but it was played in the 80s

Can you be more descriptive about the show? There are probably several shows like this.

On the children's series Square One, there was a recurring segment called Mathnet that was a parody of the detective series Dragnet. It featured a pair of detectives who were partners that solved crimes while explaining mathematical concepts.


Haha, I remember that
